# Where in php source code are the logging modules?

Tags: php

This is about php source and not the php language per say...

I have the source code for php and I would like to enable some additional logging.  The idea is to log when certain actions take place with the need for someone to code in the logging call.  For example, whenever someone makes a call to a database, log that the call was made and have some of the connection details sent to the logger.  I know I could use mysqli_get_client_stats to get some of these details but that requires me to code each php script to get those values and print/send to logger, but I'd prefer to extend such a call to automatically log that for me.

What should I be looking for in the source to do this?  I assume I can find the necessary functions I want to automatically enable logging for, but I've yet to figure out what I would call to log whatever it is I want to log.

Comment: where did you learn that such a feature exists? if I had to start looking, id take a look in the `Zend/` directory and look for the code that handles function calls. like maybe `zend_API.c`. also, xdebug hooks into every function call, so looking at how they do it might help.

Comment: I did not learn such a feature exists, but php HAS the ability to log.  For example, you can call error_log and that will send a message to the php log.  Thus there has to be some internal logging capabilities for this call to work.  I'd like to know where this functionality is in the source code and how to use it.

Comment: [The xdebug extension lets you trace all function calls](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace). So, if you enable xdebug tracing, then grep the output, might you get the information you're after?  If not... what specifically are you looking to log?

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to modify php source code (the c code) to log an event.  It looks like `sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_conf.c` holds the function for error_log.  Can I simply call that function within another function or is there something lower I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler method than meddling with sources would be **monkey patching**, using [runkit](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit) and redefining the functions you need.

## Runkit

You could for example [rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-rename.php) the old `whatever()` function to `old_whatever()`, and define a new `whatever()` wrapper function that logs and then calls `old_whatever()`. To do this throughout the application, you could use [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

Example

> Note: By default, only userspace functions may be removed, renamed, or
> modified. In order to override internal functions, **you must enable the
> `runkit.internal_override` setting in `php.ini`**.

```
runkit_function_rename('mysqli_query', 'xyzzy_query');

/* override mysqli_query (procedural version; the OO version is analogous,
   see documentation for runkit at the above links) */
function mysqli_query($link, $query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {
   $fp = fopen("logs/mysqli.log", "a");
   fwrite($fp, "-- query\n{$query}\n");
   fclose($fp);
   $ret = xyzzy_query($link, $query, $resultmode);
   // Additional logging of results, number of rows, etc. goes here
   return $ret;
}
```

Since you need this to happen on *every single script*, you need to include the above code in all of your scripts.

Normally you **only include it in the base level require scripts** or entry points (e.g. `index.php`) so that it is executed *first* and is executed *exactly once*. If you have a great many entry points, you can use `auto_prepend`. What you *really* do then is you create a wrapper script

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/mysqli_rewriting.php');
?>
```

and **auto-include** it in every PHP script using the `auto_prepend` directive in `php.ini` or the appropriate Apache stanza / `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "monkeypatcher.php"
```

Note: the monkeypatcher file must be in one of the directories in the **php include path**; if the latter is empty, you need to add to it, say, a "/patches" folder, then put the monkeypatcher file in there. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362691/how-can-i-specify-an-auto-prepend-file-in-my-htaccess-file-without-hardcoding-t).

## Sources

If you want to *modify PHP sources*, I think that your best bet is to leverage the `syslog` facility. The PHP error functions you found will interrupt processing and/or sending output to the error handlers, so if you went down that road, you would *also* have to provide/modify the error handlers in all of your scripts. Which would get you to autoprepending all over again.

The syslog facility on the other hand does *require syslog capability*, which is usually bundled on Unix platforms and... not so reliable on Windows ones (actually, I'm not up to date with Windows 7+ and Server 2008+; they might be working now).

If you decide to use syslog, just choose an appropriate log level to be sent to a file of your choice. Configure `syslogd` to receive those messages and send them wherever you want.

Then add in `main/php.h` (around line 306, for example)

```
#ifdef HAVE_SYSLOG_H
int logprintf(const char *format, ...);
#endif

/* PHPAPI void php_error(int type, const char *format, ...); */
PHPAPI void php_error_docref0(const char *docref TSRMLS_DC, int type, const char *format, ...)
    PHP_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT(printf, PHP_ATTR_FMT_OFFSET + 3, PHP_ATTR_FMT_OFFSET + 4);
PHPAPI void php_error_docref1(const char *docref TSRMLS_DC, const char *param1, int type, const char *format, ...)
```

and in `main/main.c`, somewhere - for example after `php_verror`:

```
/* {{{ logprintf
*/
int logprintf(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int size;
    va_start(args, format);
    size = vspprintf(&buffer, 0, format, args);
    #ifdef HAVE_SYSLOG_H
    /* LOG_LOCAL3 is reserved for local use */
    php_syslog(LOG_LOCAL3, "%s", buffer);
    #endif
    efree(buffer);
    va_end(args);
    return size;
}
/* }}} */
```

At this point you can "talk" directly to syslog from anywhere in the PHP code with the same syntax of `printf()`.

If needed you can use a `#define` to include the filename and line where the log call happened, and have it included in the output.

You want to log a query (btw: be careful of logging passwords and sensitive information...), you find *all* the places where the query is passed to the server, and for example in

```
ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c (line 332)

+++ /* Add logging */
+++ logprintf("running MySQL query: '%s'", stmt->active_query_string);

if (mysql_real_query(H->server, stmt->active_query_string,
    stmt->active_query_stringlen) != 0) {
    pdo_mysql_error_stmt(stmt);
    PDO_DBG_RETURN(0);
}
```

Drawbacks

Keep in mind that there are many entry points for the API, even from PHP (prepared statements, straight queries, emulated-prepare queries, ...). You'll need to log them *all*. If you wanted to only log MySQL queries (the method above allows logging whatever you want), you'd be **waaaaay** better off by asking *MySQL* to log the queries it receives. You can log all the queries, and even only those slower than a given time.

Comment: So how would I perform the monkey patching with an mysqli method?  I know I can rename one of those methods, but how do I create a wrapper function that is called the same way I would normally call a mysqli function.  For example, if I would want to run error_log every time I ran mysqli_query, how would you do this without impacting existing scripts?

Comment: I've added an example, but am currently unable to test it. Get back to me if there's any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you would need to edit the PHP source to do this. You could easily do this by doing something like extending `mysqli` and writing your own logging routine that runs every time you run `query()`.

```
class MyLog extends mysqli {
     public function query($sql, $mode) {
          // Do your logging here
          return parent::query($sql, $mode);
     }
}
```

Then just call this connector as you would normally.

Comment: This would work but if I had a multitude of existing scripts I'd have to go back and modify all of these scripts.  If I get under the php hood this would just 'happen'.

Comment: Actually, is there a way to create a class to extend query like this and have existing scripts use this extension and not the original one?  My first thought is that I have to `include` the file that includes that class, correct?

Comment: I'm partial to [autoloading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/791899/2370483) myself, but yes, you would need to include it in some fashion.